# Still show element in web page even if display: none

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ruby-on-rails, erb

I use ERB (Embedded Ruby) to develop frontend of the page.

I want to implement filters by changing the `display` of elements when the designated checkbox is triggered.  However, some of the elements still show on the screen after setting the display to none.
Here is my code.

**html**

```html
<div class="log_student_ability_list border border-dark mb-3 p-3 rounded mt-2 col-md-12 col-12" id="<%= log.id %>">
    some sub elements
</div>
```

**script**

```js
  const log_student_abilities_list = <%= raw @log_student_abilities.to_json%>;
  var editor_list = <%= raw @editor_log_cnt_list.to_json%>;
  var ability_list = <%= raw @ability_score_list.keys.to_json%>;
  var editor_status = {} // will be initialzed in the function which won't be listed here
  var ability_status = {} // will be initialzed in the function which won't be listed here
  var score_status = {
    'score_1': true,
    'score_0': true
  }
```

```js
  function score_filter_on_click() {
    $('.score_select_form_item').on('change', function(){
      score_status[$( this ).attr('id')] = $( this ).prop("checked")
      refreshShow();
    });
  }
```

```js
  function refreshShow(){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(`.log_student_ability_list:hidden`).css("display", "block");
    log_student_abilities_list.forEach(log => {
      if(editor_status[log.editor_member_id] && score_status['score_' + log.score]){
        var exist = log.ability_list.length === 0 ? true : false
        log.ability_list.forEach(a_id => {
          if(ability_status[a_id] === true){
            exist = true
          }
        })
        if(exist === false){
          $(`.log_student_ability_list#${log.id}`).css("display", "none");
        }
      }
      else{
        event.preventDefault();
        $(`.log_student_ability_list#${log.id}`).css("display", "none");
      }
    })
  }
```

1. I've tried both `.hide()` and  `.css("display", "none")` but none of them work.
2. I've tried `event.preventDefault()` to prevent unexpected accident, but it didn't work.
3. I also check display status

```js
$(`.log_student_ability_list#${log.id}`).is(":visible")
```

after

```js
$(`.log_student_ability_list#${log.id}`).hide();
```

and found that some of the element **return false when checking visibility**, but **still show on the screen**.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check the CSS of tag `$(`.log_student_ability_list#${log.id}`)`

Is there any CSS like `display: block !important`?